# Merging/combining and matching data frames with unequal number of rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, match, cbind

Let's say I have two data.frames `df1` and `df2`:

```
> df1
    Var1   Var2
1    "A"    "D"
2    "B"    "E"
3    "C"    "F"

> df2
    Var3   Var4
1    "C"    "H"
2    "B"    "I"
3    "G"    "J"
4    "A"    "K"
```

I want to combine/merge `df1` with `df2` in a way that the values of `Var1` and `Var3` are matched where possible and `NA` otherwise. The important thing is that I want to preserve the mapping between the values of `Var1`and `Var2`. In this simple example I would end up with:

```
> df2
    Var3   Var4   Var1   Var2
1    "C"    "H"    "C"    "F"
2    "B"    "I"    "B"    "E"
3    "G"    "J"     NA     NA
4    "A"    "K"    "A"    "D"
```

Any ideas on a general way to achieve this? The number of variables in each data.frame is not necessarily equal in reality as in this example. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `match`:

```
Indices <- match(df2$Var3, df1$Var1)

df2$Var1<-df1$Var1[Indices]
df2$Var2<-df1$Var2[Indices]
```

Comment: or more simply, `cbind(df2, df1[match(df2$Var3, df1$Var1),])`